# Cascading drop down menus Using a4j Support

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am new to JSF. I have 3 cascading SelectOneMenu i.e Countries, States and Cities. The functionlity is when country is selected corressponding states are populated and when state is selected cities are populated.
I am using a4j:support tag for implementing it. My managed bean is in request scope and is spring managed beans.
I have written ActionListener for CountriesChanged(), StatesChanged() and CitiesChanged().

In my application when one selects countries, action event is fired and states are populated.
However, when one changes states, it throws "Validation Error : Value is not valid"

It would be helpful if somebody guides me proper direction.

Comment: Can you post the jsf page and the backing bean source?

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare exactly the same list of states during the form submit request as it was during the form display request. JSF will namely re-validate the submitted value against the list of available items. In case of a request scoped bean, you have to prepare it in the bean's (post)constructor. Another way is to put the bean in the new JSF 2.0 view scope so that the bean don't get recreated whenever you submit the form against the same view.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since my bean is spring managed I tried to prepare the states in my init-method. But still no luck. Could you please provide me any code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I can't go in detail as I don't use Spring. To the point, you should prepare exactly the same list of states based on the selected country. The selected country should be available as a request parameter.